# Conditions for continuity of \min function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function.
Fix $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider
$$\psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\ \psi(y)=\min_{\xi\in[x_0,y]}\phi(\xi)\ .$$
Is $\psi$ a continuous function? In particular does $\psi(y)\to\phi(x_0)$ as $y\to x_0$?

What if we further assume that $\phi$ has bounded variation on compact intervals, or that $\phi$ is $C^1$? can we hope to obtain a positive answer?

Comment: Your example $\phi$ is not continuous function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: yes you are right. So the counter-example is not valid. I was changing the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any continuous $\phi$, $\psi$ is continuous. Pick any point $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon < 0$. Consider $\psi(y) = \min_{\xi \in [x_0, y]} \phi(\xi)$. By continuity of $\phi$ at $y$, there's  $\delta > 0$ such that if $|z - y| < \delta$, then $|\phi(z) - \phi(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Assume that $z < y$ (the case $z > y$ is similar) Now $|\psi(z) - \psi(y)| = |\min_{\xi \in [x_0, z]} \phi(\xi)  -\min_{\xi \in [x_0, y]} \phi(\xi)|$. The minimum value of $\phi$ on $[x_0, y]$ is taken either somewhere in $[x_0, z]$ or in $[z, y]$. In the first case, $\psi(z) = \psi(y)$, in the second case the minimum value of $\phi$ on $[x_0, z]$ is different from the minimum value of $\phi$ on $[x_0, y]$ by not more than $\epsilon$, essentially because $|\phi(u) - \phi(v)| < \epsilon$ for $u, v \in [z, y]$ (I'll leave careful analysis of the possible cases for you).